# Extrude edge along roof angle

Tags: modeling, edges

I'm trying to extend an edge from the existing roof face axis. 
How can I do this? I want it to go all the way down to the lower part of the building. It must connect there (I want a edge there too so the remaining right part of that lower building will be cut off).

[image: example mesh diagram]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create new transform orientation for that edge.

Select side face of the roof. In the <kbd>N</kbd> panel create new transform orientation (you can create it pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd>, as Gonzou mentioned):

[image]

The created orientation should be selected as active. If it isn't, in <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> menu select this orientation (it will be called something like `Face`). Switch to Edge selection mode, select your edge, extrude it, cancel moving by <kbd>Esc</kbd> and start grabbing pressing <kbd>G</kbd> twice.

[image]

Comment: I think both answers are good but this seems to be the most simple one :) Thanks

Comment: Quick tip: To quickly create a new transformation orientation you may use a Shift + Alt + Space shortcut.

Comment: Did you mean `Ctrl`+`Alt`+`Space` ? And thanks, I will edit the answer

Comment: Yeah, Ctrl + Alt + Space of course :). My mistake.

Answer (score 10):

1. Select the face of the roof.
2. Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>NumPad 7</kbd> to move the view to that face.
3. Change the *Transform Orientation* (in the 3D view header) to "*View*".
4. Press <kbd>E</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> (to exclude the Y axis from the movment)

A new edge perfectly aligned to the roof.

Altogether in an animated gif:
[image: animated gif]

Comment: +1 This one is better then Mr. Zak's because after a while of doing this you can end up with ALOT of transforms.

Comment: @GiantCowFilms As for me, I drop them immediately after transforms. The View method doesn't work for me because it makes me to recover the 3D view alignment which I don't like. But maybe that's just me.

Comment: @MrZak http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?218403. I dont personally use it, but looks useful.

Comment: This would work as well with the knife tool to make a cut on the face on the other side of the building.

Comment: @cegaton I'm not following. will you head over to chat and explain further?

Comment: @David When I try to use this method, the extrusion will be upward instead of down. See [http://i.imgur.com/su3CUar.png](http://i.imgur.com/su3CUar.png)

Comment: @Nique for the way your house is facing, you will have to exclude the X axis. Also make sure that your set Transform Orientation  to "View"

Comment: @Daniel Aha! I tried that too but .. i forgot to disable snapping lol. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In the image above a loop cut was made.  Next we viewed the angles as indicated.  The vertex of the loop cut was moved until angles were within tolerance.  You may may have zero tolerance capable hands.  In this example the angle in question is about 44 degrees.  Finish by adding and deleting faces.

The loop cut allows deletion of faces.

Comment: Very well explained. But i'll stick with Mr Zak's answer because its simple :). Thanks!