# Cannot continue my model because of unexplained angles in the X Y and Z orientations

Tags: vertices, constraints, edges, tracking

Hey everyone (something happened to my account so had to ask this question again),

I'm very new to Blender and i'm learning a lot through tutorials. I have come to a part where I cannot continue because the orientation of my X Y and Z is completely off for some reason. In every orientation (Normal, Local, Global), it doesnt seem to align to the right path my vertices and edges have. This way I cannot move my edges and vertices around without them crooking to the left, or down. I have tried looking at other posts and problems on Google too, but I cannot find it and I also don't know how to describe this problem to be honest because I am so new to Blender. Now it seems like I cannot even individually pick a vertice or edge without moving the entire thumb.

- How can I make the X Y and Z orientation back to the default settings so i can move my vertices and edges in the right direction?
- How can I tell Blender I want to move around vertices and edges without moving the entire thumb or object around?

I have attached an image here.

Thank you in advance, if I could fix this problem, and understand this for the next time, it would help me incredibly.

[image: Orientation problem]

Comment: It looks like the object is placed in such a way that default axes don't suit your needs. One way would be to align view to the mesh like here - http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38487/1245. Another way would be to create custom [transform orientation](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/transform_orientations.html) and move / extrude verts/faces along it.

Comment: @zeffii Yeah for some reason, Google Chrome didn't let me registrate with the un-registrated account I asked the question with, so I had to create a new account because I like to be registrated onto this forum to learn more about this problem and this program. I don't know how to delete the question of the un-registrated account so I wanted to ask this question again with my real newly made account. I know it is an almost exact duplicate... Really, I'm trying my best...

Comment: @Kelli Don't worry, we can have a Mod remove it for you.

Comment: @kelli it's OK. it'll get cleared up.

Answer (score 5):

Try to change the *transform orientation* type to ***Global*** (in your case it is set to *Normal*).
[image]

You may also add a ***custom transformation*** for precise axes set up. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> and name it in the *Transform Orientations* panel of the *Properties Shelf* (<kbd>N</kbd>). In my case I filled the edge loop with a face (<kbd>F</kbd>) to set up the axes along its normal. Then added a *custom transformation*, deleted the face (<kbd>X</kbd>-->*Faces*) and extruded the edge loop along local Z axis (pressed <kbd>E</kbd>, then <kbd>Z</kbd> twice).
[image]

If the entire thumb moves while transforming it means, that you've enabled the ***proportional editing***. Disable it.
[image]